# IBAction button to send a command to ip camera to rotate. The command is a html link with username password and CGI command but it redirects to safari

Tags: iphone, xcode, redirect, cgi

I'm trying to make an app in xcode for my iphone to control my ip camera so I've setupa controller with a webview which loads a html link to my ip cam. I've also setup some IBActions linked to some buttons trying to control the camera movements when pressing the buttons (right, left up, down).
Each IBAction linked to the buttons looks like

```
-(IBAction)camMoveUp
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2/decoder_control.cgicommand=0&user=myusername&pwd=mypassword"]]
}
```

This action, when sent to the internet/router triggers my camera to move up. 
It works but everytime I hit a button it redirects to safari and displays a message "ok" on the screen. The camera moves where was directed to, BUT HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT THIS WITHOUT BEING REDIRECTED TO SAFARI EVERY SINGLE TIME I PRESS A BUTTON?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)camMoveUp
        {
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2/decoder_control.cgicommand=0&user=myusername&pwd=mypassword"]];

// Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSLog(@"response=%@",response );
}
```

Or Else you can Take a webView inside your View and open the URL

```
   -(IBAction)camMoveUp
    {

//Create Webview Programatically 
    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,100.0, 320.0,360.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor Whitecolor]];
[self.view addsubview:webview];
//Load The URL to Open
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://192.168.1.2/decoder_control.cgicommand=0&user=myusername&pwd=mypassword";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
webview.delegate=self;
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


}
```

If you want to do some activity after page loads then you can use webview delegate functions.
check [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/) is a complete tutorial For WebView.

Comment: Thanks so much, first option works like a charm but the second one is a bit unclear to me and I would like to try it. I can see that you've created a *webView but it doesn't come up in my connections inspector to connect it to a web view object. How do I get to see that green web view you've created? and where do I enter the url address of my actual camera image? Sorry I'm quite new to xcode and c

Comment: I Just created the webview programatically so no need to connect just put all the codes i written.
-(IBAction)camMoveUp
{
}

Comment: I've tried that way first but nothing comes up, and the link to my actual stream is nowhere in this code. First one is based on a webview with the stream preloaded and your code is sending the commands to the camera to move. But for your second code I've removed my webview as you have created another one but it doesn't show up and I still can't see how I can see anything without entering the link to the stream??

Comment: I get it, so the second method you gave me creates and loads link/url. I had to replace the link from above with the actual streaming link and it works as it creates a webview and the url opends in there. Thanks! First method was more what I was looking for so Thanks a lot ! and as soon as I get to 15 points you will be the first one to rate up. Thanks for now.